# padrino - adding html options to submit button on button_to

Tags: ruby, padrino

```
button_to 'Submit',url(:account, :login)
```

generates form like this:

```
<form action="/account/login" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

but I want to generate something like this:

```
<form action="/account/login" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="myclass">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of tag helpers can receive a block to capture inner html:

```
button_to 'Submit', url(:base, :index) do
  submit_tag 'Submit', :class => 'myclass'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should work:

```
<%= button_to 'Submit', {:controller => :account, :action => :login}, :class => 'myform' %>
```

The third parameter to [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) is `html_options`. If you can only alter the form using the html_options, then you could use a css selector like this:

```
form.myform input {}
```

Comment: it adds the class in the form element not the submit button

Comment: you could use a css selector like this: form.myform input {}